# Key press cooldown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on solo project that is horizontal 2D infinite runner. I have a problem in jumping mechanics where player can hold the jump button and jump as soon as he touches the ground. I want to force player to release the button to be able to jump again. I want to make same mechanics when he is floating(at the end of the jump when player starts falling down its y velocity is being reduced for few bits of second). I am following single responsibility principle so jumping and floating are 2 seperate scripts.

I have tried to implement a timer that will count while player is touching the ground and after some time the player would be able to jump again, but didn't manage to get asked result because you can hold the jump button all the time and after determined time spent on ground player would just jump again without releasing the button.

```
public class Jumping : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isJumping;
    public bool isGrounded;
    public float speedUp;
    public float verticalAxis;

    public float timePassed;
    public float jumpLimit;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        verticalAxis = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        if (verticalAxis > 0 && timePassed == 0)
        {
            isJumping = true;
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (isJumping)
        {
            Jump();
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.tag == "Ground")
        {

            isGrounded = true;
            timePassed = 0f;
        }
    }


    private void Jump()
    {
        isGrounded = false;
        //Modifying y component of players rigidbody(jumping)
        Vector2 velocity = Vector2.up * speedUp * verticalAxis;
        rb.velocity = velocity;

        //Counting time when jumping 
        timePassed += Time.deltaTime;
        if (timePassed >= jumpLimit)
        {
            isJumping = false;
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. I have tried to shrink the code in this question as stackoverflow suggests but I didn't know what to cut out because according to me everything is relevant and crucial to solving the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the part where you are counting while player is grounded

Answer (score 1):

without knowing the rest of your code I would use an additional flag and obviously something for getting the cool down delay like

```
public float jumpCoolDownTime;
private float coolDownTimer;
private bool canJump;

void Update()
{
    // if no can jump you can't jump again
    if(!canJump)
    {
        verticalAxis = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        if (verticalAxis > 0)
        {
            canJump = false;
            isJumping = true;
            coolDownTimer = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // run timer to enable jump again
        if(isGrounded) coolDownTimer += Time.deltaTime;

        if(coolDownTimer >= jumpCoolDownTime)
        {
            canJump = true;
        }
    }
}
```

---

You could however simplify the code a bit using [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

```
public bool isJumping;
public float speedUp;
public float verticalAxis;

public float jumpLimit;
public float coolDownTime;

private Rigidbody2D rb;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    rb = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
    // do nothing is already jumping
    if(isJumping) return;

    verticalAxis = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    if (verticalAxis > 0)
    {
        // start jumping
        StartCoroutine(Jump());
    }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.tag != "Ground") return;

    isGrounded = true;
    StartCoroutine(CoolDown());
}

private IEnumerator Jump()
{
    isJumping = true;
    isGrounded = false;
    coolDownTimer = 0;

    var timePassed = 0f;
    while(timePassed < jumpLimit)
    {
        // wait for the FixedUpdate call
        yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();

        Vector2 velocity = Vector2.up * speedUp * verticalAxis;
        rb.velocity = velocity;
    }
}

private IEnumerator CoolDown()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeoncds(coolDownTime);

    isJumping = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the axis to get the jump, you can see if the player have released the button by:

```
if (GetAxis("Vertical") == 0.0) { //Button up
     // do stuff
}
if(GetAxis("Vertical") > 0)
{
     //Button down, is jumping
}
```

In Unity axis aren't `booleans`, they are coefficients, if you play with a controller you can set different behaviors for different intensities.

Comment: Thanks guys, I ditched getaxis and instead used Input.GetMouseButtonDown as I have read that that function is close to touches in mobile and for now it's working pretty well. I implemented button cooldown solution from derHugo and it's great. But I think I will not use rigidbody to move the player as I found out that you can use triggers with kinematic rigidbody tro detect collisions and downside of using rigidbody was unequal jumping that I am not able to solve for few days now. Thanks for your help!